# how to query multiple categories in wordpress?

Tags: query

I am trying to query multiple category in wordpress but no luck, I don’t see anything wrong with my code.

Herewith my code below :

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=1&cat=5,1');

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

  get_template_part('loop', 'single-home');

endwhile;
```

Comment: The problem with this question is that you don't clarify whether you want posts in either category or that they have to be in both categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like this

```
query_posts( array( 'category__in' => array(5,1), 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

or

```
$my_query = new WP_query(array('category__and' => array(5,1))); 
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Comment: it alright the first one it working

Comment: if my answer helps you then please accept it as the answer by clicking the tick symbol

Answer (score 2):

First of all, never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

You should rather use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create custom queries

Secondly, your problem is your `posts_per_page` parameter. That is set to `1`. What this means is that one post will be retrieved which will come from either cat 1 or cat 5, depending which post is the newest between the two cats. You have to increase `1` to retrieve more posts, set `1` to `-1` to retrieve all posts from these two categories.

You can also remove the `posts_per_page` parameter and replace it with `nopaging=true` to retrieve all posts.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMO. Avoid using query_posts.